Merging an administrative dataset with survey data in the context of a regression discontinuity design: what things should I consider?
I have an administrative dataset that contains the running variable for a Regression Discontinuity Design (RDD) study. I plan to merge this dataset with survey data that was collected for other purposes, in order to obtain the dependent variables for my study. Besides external validity, are there any other methodological pitfalls that this procedure migth cause?
Also, I might want to use survey weights to improve the external validity. Does that makes sense? If so, do you know how to implement them with the rdrobust command (either in STATA or R)? The survey in question uses a complex sample design.

Common issues with administrative data are that the variable definitions are not what you would have used if you were collecting the data for this purpose ('concept') or that the same nominal time points aren't the same time periods. It depends on the type of data, of course.
Assuming the administrative data are for the same population as the survey, I would calibrate/rake the data to the population to improve external validity.  Ideally if you want inference to the data generating process you want to treat the administrative population as a sample (eg simple random sample) from the data generating process and the survey as a complex sample from the population.  However, the only software I know of to do this will require record-level information for the population, which probably isn't feasible.
Assuming the sample is much smaller than the population, you can probably assume that the sampling variance is much larger than the model variance of the population. In that scenario I would calibrate the sample to the administrative population and just consider the sampling variance.  I don't know enough Stata to know how you'd do it there.
